# vertical scroll - jquery alternative to flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scroll

anyone know a plug in that can make a similar thing that is showed is the second example - (JC Play List Minimal Skin)

http://www.jumpeyecomponents.com/Flash-Components/User-Interface/JC-Play-List-285/examples.htm

only the scroll, not the background image

i have some problems with flash :)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the [HoverScroll jQuery Plugin](http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/)? There's also [this plugin](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/vertical.html), which isn't *exactly* the same as the Flash example.

Comment: I agree, it's not as silky-smooth as the Flash version. You could probably use simplyScroll (the second link) with a little bit of tweaking.

Comment: i will seen the source of the first, and after that, i decide. thanks

Comment: as i expect, it is easily to make it more smooth. Just change the interval values to small intervals :)